# netbeans c++ deployment

Tags: deployment, netbeans, ubuntu, g++, packaging

I had developed a small program  in netbeans using c++. I need to know how can i deploy/run the package on another linux system

Abdul Khaliq

Comment: Is there any dependencies (libraries) ?

Comment: yes the project successfully compiles runs in NB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen your code, you probably missing XML files in the current folder... where the executable is located... paste then and then run as ./your-executable

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use a [makefile](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/) to recompile on your target machine which will ensure that your program is deployed properly.

Comment: Thats ok but Netbeans compiles a package in dist folder I need to know how do to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, once compiled, your executable will need several libraries. Chance is that those libraries will also be available on the target linux system.

Thus, you can simply copy your executable over to the other system. If you run ldd on your executable, you should see the list of libraries your executable is dynamically loading. Those libraries should be available on the target system as well.

In case your executable makes use of resources such as images and other binary files, you can use a resource system (e.g. Qt Resource System) and compile those binary files into your executable.

The easiest way to test is to do the copy, run

```
ldd yourExecutable
```

on the target system. It will tell you if you are missing any library. Install those libraries using the system package manager.

Of course, you also have the option to statically build all libraries into your executable. However, this is not recommended since it makes the executable too large and complicates matters.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a makefile as suggested. I know that NetBeans can generate one, but it's been a while since I last did so. Maybe this can help: http://forums.netbeans.org/topic3071.html

Answer (score 0):

What type of package is your netbeans compiler creating? deb,rpm? If you are moving the package to a different linux install you will need to use that distributions package type. Ubuntu - deb
Fedora/Redhat - rpm
etc...
I'm not sure how you change this in netbeans but I'm pretty sure it has the ability to. A google search could help you more.